# password_hash() in PHP

Tags: php, password-hash

I am using the following PHP code to hash a user's password.

```
$options = [
'cost' => 10,
'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
];

$hash = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Is this method safe? Is the password getting salted?

Comment: The documentation for [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) **specifically** says ___Do not make up your own SALT___ You wont do as good a jobs as the function does unless you are a cryptograhpic EXPERT. Also the ability to create your own SALT is deprecated, (will soon be removed) so why bother writing code that wont run soon!

Comment: *"Is this method safe? Is the password getting salted?"* - Short answer: Yes. Longer answer: Consult the duplicates the question was closed with. If you're still unsure about it, don't use it and don't get on the web.

Comment: Take note that in PHP 7.0.0, salting is deprecated *"**Warning** The salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default."* as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is best to omit the salt parameter. Without this parameter, the function will generate a cryptographically safe salt, from the random source of the operating system.

Ref: php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#111620

Comment: Although correct, this is a weak answer.

Comment: This was also quoted directly from the manual provided from user contributed notes http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#111620 - You should have stated that. Edit: This comment as per original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44587681/1

Comment: So what about the 'cost' that is passed along with the salt?